# FOSUserbundle registration date

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed FOSUserbundle on my server and customized my frontend. Everything works fine. Now i'll add Register Date into my database. I have added this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="register_date", type="date")
*/
private $registerDate;
```

into entity User.php and after database update, this column was succesfully added into database. Now after registring, it should automatically add registration date into database. What should i change/add into my code so that it works?
thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add to `User` entity a constructor (or modify it, if already exists):

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (empty($this->registerDate)) {
        $this->registerDate = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```